# How to pass XML array into Shopify API call

Tags: php, api, shopify

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
   <id type="integer">100159400</id>
<title>150 Watt Mini Stereo Power Amplifier</title>
<variants type="array">
<variant>
<id type="integer">233139732</id>
<grams type="integer">700</grams>
<inventory-quantity type="integer">222</inventory-quantity>
 </variant>
</variants>
</product>
```

It does not work for me. I'm parsing xml array in shopify api call

```
$recurring_application_charge = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/products/109720638.xml', $product);
```

here i'm parsing single value but i need to pass dynamic value which i have stored in database after insertion of record in shopify store. Even update command doesn't work for me for a single product. Please help me out,

Comment: Are you using a library or raw HTTP requests? Make sure the Content-Type header is set (e.g. text/xml). Also please let us know what response you get back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sandeep's PHP adapter,you have to change the Content type to XML in (Shopify.php). By default adapter is using Json format to POST requests.